# Proper way of getting img data from a http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `service` to fetch all the users **profile image**. The problem is that the img will only show when the request was finished/completed.

What I want is to show the img that already been called/loaded.

**getImgService**

```
uploadService.getImgs().then(function (data) {
    vm.img = data;
    myCache.put('imgsData', vm.img);
    return vm.img;
});
```

I already tried to research my problem and found **pre-loading** but can't find an article that I can follow.

Comment: So now you have one service that promises value of _all_ loaded images that you can process, while you want to get promise for _each_ loaded image separately to process it as soon as possible?
If so, why you do not return array of promises so that you can loop over and attach same function to each promised image separately?

Comment: @andy thats what i want to do. But don't know how thanks for commenting btw.

Comment: I am not sure if you can share source of `getImgs()` so I will answer without getting into details how your service should work, only on how to consume result.

Comment: Feedback from your site would be appreciated. Upvoting or accepting answer even more. If you want more support on converting you original code also let me know.

Comment: It looks like @andy requested feedback from you, Priz, nearly a year ago. Since he/she gave an answer, would you do that now please?

Answer (score 1):

Make your `getImgs()` returning array of promises instead of one promise. And each promise in array should return single image data. With that modification you need to register same callback for all returned promises so that it reacts on each image loaded event and caches it immediatelly. Example:

```
function cacheImage(data) {
    if (!vm.img) {
        vm.img = []; // assuming array store of single image data
        myCache.put(‘imgsData’, vm.img);
    }
    vm.img.push(data); // add to array next image data
}

uploadService.getImgs().forEach(imgPromise => imgPromise.then(cacheImage));
```